# Android 4.0.3 no longer compatible with my phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been developing on a Droid X2 w/ Android 2.3.4 for about 4 months. The SDK I used the entire time was Android 4.0.3, which worked w/o incident. I downloaded and set up the 2.2 SDK for use with an older phone, and now no SDK is 'compatible' with my phone. I've messed with the manifest (min/max/target version), creating new simple programs and tried running with that, nothing works. I've also reinstalled everything. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the specific error message?

Comment: No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add an new Android Virtual Device?

Comment: What's the minSdkVersion in your manifest? In your case it should be 10 (=2.3.3) or something lower!

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:maxSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

Comment: I've never used maxSdkVersion myself... what happens if you remove that part?

Comment: No difference. I appreciate your suggestion, though.

Comment: In your projects file "project.properties" did you change target=android-15 to target=android-8 ? Sometimes this file won't get updated automatically

Comment: I have default.properties and project.properties both set to 10, since 2.3.4 is level 10.

Comment: I can't believe I've spent like 3 hours working on this.

Comment: I'm working on an app that is compatible down to 2.2 (= level 8), but also uses features from level 15 if available. My settings are as follows: manifest: minSdkVersion=8, targetSdkVersion=15; project.properties: target=android-15.